# Spring MVC: Moving from WebMvcAutoConfiguration to WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, losing static pages

Tags: spring-mvc

With a Spring MVC application that extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration, I can serve static pages from a project-top-level directory "static", which is quite convenient. (Spring also seems to package the static pages in the built jar file?)

But I need more control over my configuration, so I'm instead extending my application from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. When I do this, I lose the static pages.

What's the Spring MVC way to have my cake and eat it too? Preferably without using xml (annotations and code)?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

Sure, depending on where your resources are, you can add this in your WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
     .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "/PATH/TO/OTHER/RESOURCES")
}
```

That should get your resources going again. See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) for more details.

Comment: did this work for you? I am facing the same issue where once i added   my own WebConfig which extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport i do not get the static content which is under /META-INF/resources.

I tried the solution provided by @tanenbring but that is not working. May be its because I am using WebMvcConfigurationSupport and not Adapter